# AWS Lambda, RDSServices, Aurora MySql serverless, Prepared SQL statement not executing or returning from RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Everything has been working just fine until trying to use prepared statements.
I create a params object like normal but add the parameters property:

```
{
    "database": "ZZZZ",
    "secretArn": "XXXXX",
    "resourceArn": "YYYYYYYY",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO BUILDINGS (\n        <snip>     </snip>    )",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "bld_id",
            "value": {
                "stringValue": "440a8357-330f-44bc-ba3d-b71dbf694100"
            }
        },
        <snip></snip>
    ],
    "continueAfterTimeout": false,
    "includeResultMetadata": true
}
```

Then a function is called to execute within a try/catch:

```
let sqlData = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
```

This never returns, no errors are logged. But lambda continues to execute. and no data is inserted into db.

I find it odd that console logs after this call do not post to CloudWatch, but the next call to this function occurs.  All async calls are using await.

And yes, I asked ChatGPT first but that was a rabbit hole. But didn't want to waste anyone's time on simple stuff.  As of now I am baffled.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad. I was using await on the call and it was inside a forEach statement which does not await.